# pixel index out of range: snake game

Tags: python, pygame, collision, pygame-surface

I am trying to code an snake game and use collision to make the snake eat the food. well I am having error as it is saying there's

> ```
> index error: pixel index our of range
> ```

Here's some code that could help show the problem.

```py
collision_colour = YELLOW
colour = screen.get_at((400,300))

if dx > 0:
        collision_x = playerRect.right + 1
        collision_y = playerRect.centery
        collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x,collision_y))

elif dx < 0:
        collision_x = playerRect.left - 1
        collision_y = playerRect.centery
        collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x,collision_y))
elif dy > 0:
        collision_x = playerRect.bottom + 1
        collision_y = playerRect.centerx
        collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x,collision_y))
elif dy < 0:
        collision_x = playerRect.top - 1
        collision_y = playerRect.centerx
        collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x,collision_y))

if collision_colour == BLUE:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        startX = screenCentreX
        startY = screenCentreY
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        main = False
        gameover = True
        elapsedTime = int(time.perf_counter() - startTime)
```

Comment: Which line is the error at? Probably it means one of the paramaters to `get_at()` is smaller than 0 or greater than the size of your screen.

Comment: You have to ensure that `0 <= collision_x < screen.get_width()` and `0 <= collision_y < screen.get_height()`

Comment: Currently my screen is (800,600), how much smaller or greater do you recommend. Cause I tried doubling it, and adding a few 100's but it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that the pixel coordinates are in range of the *Surface* when you call [`set_at()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at).
Ensure that `0 <= collision_x < screen.get_width()` and `0 <= collision_y < screen.get_height()`:

```py
collision_colour = YELLOW
if dx != 0 or dy != 0:
    collision_colour = BLUE

if dx > 0 and playerRect.right + 1 + 1 < screen.get_width():
    collision_x = playerRect.right + 1
    collision_y = playerRect.centery
    collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x, collision_y))
elif dx < 0 and playerRect.left - 1 >= 0
    collision_x = playerRect.left - 1
    collision_y = playerRect.centery
    collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x, collision_y))
elif dy > 0 and playerRect.bottom + 1 < screen.get_height():
    collision_x = playerRect.bottom + 1
    collision_y = playerRect.centerx
    collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x, collision_y))
elif dy < 0 and playerRect.top - 1 >= 0
    collision_x = playerRect.top - 1
    collision_y = playerRect.centerx
    collision_colour = screen.get_at((collision_x, collision_y))

if collision_colour == BLUE:
    dx = 0
    dy = 0
    # [...]
```